# SilverStripe DropdownField default value set to blank

Tags: php, dropdown, silverstripe

Can someone help me to set blank as default in a `DropdownField` in SilverStripe 3?

Currently here is my code:

```
DropdownField::create(
    'HowHear',
    'How did you hear of this job?',
    array(
        'Indeed' => 'Indeed',
        'Caterer' => 'Caterer',
        'Gumtree' => 'Gumtree',
        'Word of mouth' => 'Word of mouth',
        'Other' => 'Other',
    )
)->addExtraClass('full-width'),
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SilverStripe 3 and 4 `DropdownField` has a function [`setEmptyString('')`](https://api.silverstripe.org/3/DropdownField.html#method_setEmptyString) that will set the default empty string:

```
DropdownField::create(
    'HowHear',
    'How did you hear of this job?',
    [
        'Indeed' => 'Indeed',
        'Caterer' => 'Caterer',
        'Gumtree' => 'Gumtree',
        'Word of mouth' => 'Word of mouth',
        'Other' => 'Other',
    ]
)->addExtraClass('full-width')->setEmptyString('')
```